# Best performance for tags in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have one table with items and one table with tags that can be linked to the items. Should I create a table where I store the relations between them or can I store the tag ids right in the item table like a column with "1,52,375" (tag ids).

I would in most cases lean towards a relation table, but I will mostly add one single tag per item and at the most 10 so I wonder if it's worth it.

If going with the relation table will I need a "loop-in-loop" where I make one query per item to fetch the tags. It seems like a lot of queries or is there a different solution?

I could also fetch all the items and tags separately in two queries and link them with php. Also loop in loop, but less database queries.

What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: definitely create a relationship table

Comment: Questions: 1) Which queries do you want to run afterw ards? (e.g...WHERE tag=52 would need a relation table) 2) Why do you need loop-in-loop (A JOIN should do it) But: Linking in php is by far the worst option.

Comment: @nCessity Yeah I need to be able to filter by the tags. That will probably be a mess if the tags are all in one column. Right now I have a tag table with id, long tag name, short tag name and user id which will be used if a tag that is not already in the table is added, so only that user will see those tags that are out of the standard tags. How would a join look for that? If I have 10 tags per item, will I get 10 full rows back per item with duplicated info? And how would a print look like without loop-in-loop to print out let's say Item Title in column one and a list of 10 tags in column 2?

Comment: 1. If you want to seach for tags you'll need a relational table. 2. remember, that string functions (what you would need to seperate the tagIds in a single column) are the slowest you can get. 3. what @nCessity said.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before and my current best solution is to have the tag table and a column for the tags separated by spaces (spaces in actual tags are replaced with #). Then use MySQL MATCH AGAINST to perform a natural language search for the tag you need in the tag column, the # character will be ignored by match against so it's not an issue. This has worked very well for me so far.

Comment: this would be considered a bad idea by most. read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @rtfm The tag column is not related to the tag table, the table is only used to record used tags and show tag suggestions. The tag columns is used almost as an extra title field from which you can perform natural language searches.

Comment: your still breaking first normal form which is the basics of relational table design

Comment: The tags aren't meant to be individual elements, they are meant to function as one single searchable title, thus it's not breaking that rule. it's essentially a keyword-rich description.

Comment: in that case, your answer is not related to the the question asked.

Comment: I'm providing a good alternative that will perform all the main tasks of tags without needing to create an extra table which the op is obviously trying to avoid, I believe that is relevant to the question asked